# Creating dynamic Checkbox at run time - getting 'undefined' error in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I create the same check box based on the data is returning dynamically.

here is my angularjs factor:

```
angular
  .module('myapp')
  .factory('$myfirstfactory', function($resource, $response, $path) {

    $myfirstfactory.prototype.$check = function(){
      return '<div class="checkbox"><input id="checkbox-'+this.id+'" type="checkbox" value="'+this.id+'"/><label for="checkbox-'+this.id+'"></label></div>';
    };

    return $myfirstfactory;

});
```

here is how I'm using the above factory

```
<div class="panel-body">
                    <table ng-gridview="grid1" data="griddata">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th data-name="$check"></th>
                                <th data-name="status">Status</th>                                    
                                <th data-name="account_number">Account</th>   
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
</div>
```

my question is; I'm getting `undefined` in the factory `this.id` how can i assign the unique id to each checkbox when it creates dynamically at run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I need a dynamic id at runtime I usually use this function:

```
function guid() {
    function _p8(s) {
        var p = (Math.random().toString(16) + "000000000").substr(2, 8);
        return s ? "-" + p.substr(0, 4) + "-" + p.substr(4, 4) : p;
    }
    return _p8() + _p8(true) + _p8(true) + _p8();
}
```

then before you return the string you can set id to the return of guid().

```
     angular.module('myapp').factory('$myfirstfactory', function($resource, $response, $path) {
        function guid() {
           function _p8(s) {
            var p = (Math.random().toString(16) + "000000000").substr(2, 8);
            return s ? "-" + p.substr(0, 4) + "-" + p.substr(4, 4) : p;
            }
          return _p8() + _p8(true) + _p8(true) + _p8();
        }

    $myfirstfactory.prototype.$check = function(){
      var id = guid();
      return '<div class="checkbox"><input id="checkbox-'+id+'" type="checkbox"    value="'+this.id+'"/><label for="checkbox-'+id+'"></label></div>';
};

return $myfirstfactory;
```

});

Comment: How would I assign the guid in my code? Can you please show

Comment: any chance you can create a plunkr so I know I have a full understanding of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this should be a directive?

```
yourApp.directive("mycheckbox",function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div class="checkbox"><input id="checkbox-{{checkboxId}}"'+
                  'type="checkbox" value="{{checkboxId"/><label'+
                  'for="checkbox-{{checkboxId}}">{{label}}</label></div>'
        scope {
          checkboxId: '@',
          label : '@'
        },
        link: function(scope) {
             // do something useful here 
        }
    };

});
```

And use it like this:

```
<mycheckbox checkbox-id="someid"></mycheckbox>
```

Comment: I can not change the code and introduce new directive code that's due to my internal team design. if you can show me modifying the existing(my) code that would be awesome.

Comment: @AbuHamzah You are actually going against the principles of Angular by not using them the correct way, any DOM related operations / extending the behavior need to be done in the directive, moreover selecting by IDs are not recommended aswel, try creating a directive with an isolated scope and it should work.